# How to add a value to property file using Jenkins parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins

I have testdata.properties file where I have many key values pairs as below

```
user=dinesh
password=dinesh123
phone=1234
```

Am using testdata.properties file to pass the input parameters to run the automation script.

Example: When I run my jenkins jobs with build parameter for example am entering phone number as 567 it should replace the value in the testdata.properties

```
phone=567
```

Is it possible to set the above parameters from Jenkins job by passing the build as String parameter or something ?

Answer (score 1):

In your build environment, you can include a shell action and echo your Jenkins parameter to the properties file.

e.g.,

```
#!/bin/bash

echo phone=$PHONE_REPLACE_SEQ >> /path/to/testdata.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`writeFile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace) step, but it will rewrite the whole file and not only replace a single value.